# User defined stored procedure - where's the execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, visual-studio-2015

SQL Server 2016, Enterprise Edition in Windows

Is there anyway to display the execution plan of a stored procedure created in C# with Visual Studio Data Tools?  This is a question that someone with Visual Studio experience probably knows the answer to. My searches on Google haven't turned up anything useful.

Here is the stored procedure in c#

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    static public void Addition (SqlInt32 a1, SqlInt32 a2, out SqlInt32 sum)
    {
        sum = a1 + a2;
    }


}
```

Here is the execution in SSMS 2017 v17.3

```
USE CLR1;

declare @sum int
exec dbo.Addition 3, 4, @sum output
select @sum
```

I have also been able to find the execution plan in cache. Even though there is a plan_handle available in dm_exec_procedure_stats, I can't seem to use a cross apply to [dm_exec_query_plan] to view it.

Comment: You might have to capture it via trace (profiler or XE). http://executionplan.blogspot.com/2012/02/execution-plan-of-clr-stored-procedure.html

Comment: I second this. Perhaps you can profile it to get the actual SQL being executed. At which point you could run manually and view the estimated/actual query plans.

Comment: What kind of execution plan are you expecting to see for this? It is just `EXEC-ing` a black box.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Actually just discovering this for the first time so not getting back an execution plan was unexpected. I simply wondered to myself, if you inherit one of these stored procedures, how do you troubleshoot performance issues without the plan.

Comment: Thank you @SqlWorldWide, I will take a look at that link.

Comment: Have you looked into using Query Store? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2016